# Wonach richtet sich das Geschlecht eines Anglizismus?

Tags: gender, anglicism

Wenn ich das Geschlecht eines Anglizismus bestimmen muss, orientiere ich mich an drei Gegebenheiten:

- Hat das Wort ein echtes Geschlecht (the mare, die Stute)?
- Welches Geschlecht hat die Übersetzung im Deutschen
- Nach welchem Geschlecht klingt das Wort

Ersteres erscheint mir verbindlich, aber die anderen zwei Orientierungen sind nicht immer eindeutig. Unterschiedliche Geschlechter, je nach Übersetzungswort:

- fir tree:

  - Die Tanne
  - Der Tannenbaum
- shop

  - Der Laden
  - Das Geschäft
- mail

  - Die Post
  - Der Brief

Ich sage „Der Computershop“ – aber mit welchem Recht?
Ich habe eine Mail bekommen, aber bin schon gefragt worden, ob ich den Mail bekommen habe (:grusel:).

Andere Beispiele, Klang?

- stack (der Keller)

  - der Frack, der Sack, der Lack
  - das Hack, das Pack
  - die Jack'
- the song, der Song, das Lied

  - der Gong, der Vietkong

Ich neige dazu „der Stack“ zu sagen, aber auch „der Song“ – aber wieso nicht „das Song“ – es heißt ja auch „das Lied“? Wegen des Klanges, weil „…ong“-Worte im Deutschen männlich sind?

#### Update: „der Download“

Dem Kommentar von Matthias entnehme ich das Beispiel des „Downloads“. Bitte überprüft: Heißt es „der Download“? Wieso? Das Herunterladen, das Abladen. Der angehängte „~vorgang“ als Erklärung sieht mir sehr wie eine post hoc Entschuldigung aus – überzeugend ist er m. E. nicht, vielmehr ein prächtiges Argument gegen die Vermutung, die nächstliegende deutsche Form würde das Geschlecht spendieren. Meine jüngste These in dieser Causa lautet „der Trenchcoat => der Download“ (aber: das Roggenbrot).

PS: Meine favorisierten Tags, [anglizismus](/questions/tagged/anglizismus) und [geschlecht](/questions/tagged/geschlecht) konnte ich mangels Reputation nicht anlegen/verwenden. [gender](/questions/tagged/gender) scheint mir falsch, und nicht einmal [englisch](/questions/tagged/englisch) fand ich als vorhandenes Tag.

#### Update und Nachtrag Nr. 2

Die Diskussion, ob ein Geschlecht zu verwenden ist, wenn es verwendet wird, ob also positivistisch zu begrüßen ist, was sich nicht mehr verhindern lässt, muss hier nicht erneut geführt werden. Es ist, glaube ich, unbestritten, dass sich früher oder später Begriffe (und somit Artikel) einbürgern; aber so, wie die Leute „3 mal weniger Spritverbrauch“ sagen, oder „in keinster Weise“ ist das, was gemacht wird, nicht immer gut, schön und richtig. Oft ist es schlecht, falsch und hässlich.

Comment: Vielleicht sollte man das experimentell angehen. Eine Gruppe denkt sich neue, fiktive Worte aus, z.B. aus dem Bereich alternative Energieerzeugung. Dann sollen die anderen diesen unabhängig voneinander ein Geschlecht zuordnen. Wäre interessant zu sehen, ob bei den Muttersprachlern dann eindeutige Verteilungen sichtbar werden. Die bisherigen Vorschläge erscheinen mir tendenziell spekulativ.

Comment: Here is a nice blog (or rather _sprachlog_ ;) ) post about „[Der Blog ist tot, es lebe das Blog](http://www.scilogs.de/wblogs/blog/sprachlog/sprachgebrauch/2011-08-25/das-blog-ist-tot-es-lebe-der-blog)“

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Eine allgemein gültige Regel gibt es meines Wissens nicht.

Ich vermute, dass viele eingedeutschte Bezeichnungen ihren Artikel von der üblichen Übersetzung oder dem ähnlichsten deutschen Begriff bekommen.

Weiters vermute ich, dass die Häufigkeit der Verwendung eines bestimmten Geschlechts ausschlaggebend ist. Damit meine ich, dass das entstandene Genus sich einbürgert, ohne dass eine logische Erklärung dafür offensichtlich ist.

Ein Beispiel dafür ist "URL" (Uniform Resource Locator), das von den meisten deutschsprachigen Menschen mit weiblichem Artikel verwendet wird (*die Adresse*), obwohl "Locator" eher auf eine männliche Verwendung schließen lassen würde.

Zu den Beispielen **spekuliere** ich:

- die E-Mail: vielleicht, weil wir *"eine Nachricht bekommen"* assoziieren?
- der Online-Shop: von "der Laden" (?), das in der Umgangssprache häufiger als "das Geschäft" verwendet wird
- der Song: Hier versagt meine Phantasie. Vielleicht hängt es doch/auch vom Klang des Worts ab? Oder von: "der Gesang"?

Answer (score 7):

Ich denke in vielen Fällen richtet sich das Geschlecht vor allem danach, mit welchem deutschen Wort der Anglizismus am ehesten assoziiert wurde zum Zeitpunkt als er in der deutschen Sprache Popularität erlangt hat. Z.B. der Computer oder der Laptop werden am ehesten als der Rechner übersetzt.

Interessant ist der Fall bei Mail bzw. E-Mail. Die weibliche Form stammt offenbar aus der Computer- bzw. Netzwerkszene und dort wurde Mail anfangs am ehesten als Nachricht übersetzt. Vor der Verbreitung von E-Mail gab es bereits andere Systeme (z.B. [BBS](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mailbox_%28Computer%29), übrigens die BBS -> die Box bzw. Mailbox) die bereits persönliche Nachrichten kannten (PMs bzw. PNs) welche oft auch als Mails bezeichnet wurden. Andererseits scheint der sächliche Artikel in Verbindung mit Mail bzw. E-Mail vor allem in der BWLer-Welt sehr verbreitet zu sein, wo es vor dem Einzug von E-Mail bereits Memos und Mailings in gedruckter Form gab und E-Mails wahrscheinlich erst mal am ehesten damit assoziiert wurden.

Comment: Wenn die damals gängige Übersetzung von *Computer* statt *Rechner* irgendwas weibliches gewesen wäre, glaubt man wirklich dass man heute *eine Computer (f)* sagen würde?  Ich glaube eher nicht.  (Obwohl es in irgendeiner Fachsprache tatsächlich *das Filter* heißen soll.)

Answer (score 7):

Im Buch „Der Dativ ist dem Genitiv sein Tod“ gibt es das Kapitel „Krieg der Geschlechter“ über dieses Thema – zwar mit einem Fokus auf Produktnamen; allerdings kann man das, glaube ich, leicht auf alle Bereiche ausdehnen. Laut Bastian Sick gibt es folgende **Grundregel**: Das Geschlecht eines Wortes richtet sich danach, *wofür* dieses Wort steht. Beispiele:

> Die Lotion, die Nivea für die Creme.
> Das Ariel, das Persil für das Waschmittel

Ausnahme:

> Der Weiße Riese – hier ist das bekannte Wort Riese stärker als das Waschmittel.

Ausnahme in die andere Richtung:

> Der Mercedes, der BMW, der Toyota, der Fiesta, der Polo für der Wagen.

Ausnahme von der Ausnahme:

> Die Citroën DS, weil DS im französischen wie das Wort für Göttin klingt.
>
> Das Astra – Hamburger Bier.
> Der Astra – ein Auto von Opel

Wörter wie „Nutella“ sollen schon zu viel Streit am Frühstückstisch geführt haben. Wenn man so ein Problem umschiffen will, kann man künstlich eine Bedeutung für das Wort hinzufügen:

> das Nutellaglas,
> die Nutellacreme,
> der Nutellabrotaufstrich

Gerade bei relativ neuen Wörtern aus Fremdsprachen kann es natürlich zu Problemen kommen. Wir benutzen instinktiv das Geschlecht des Wortes, von dem wir glauben, dass es für das Wort steht.

„Der Download“ für „der Herunterladevorgang“

„Der Mail“ für „der Brief“; allerdings sage *ich* die E-Mail, weil ich anscheinend die Nachricht meine

„Der Vietcong“ für „der Bewohner/Kämpfer/… aus Vietnam“

„Die Tanne“ allein hat ein Geschlecht, das allerdings im zusammengesetzten Wort zu „der Tannenbaum“ werden kann.

Answer (score 4):

Gerade das Thema der Artikel von Hauptwörtern in der deutschen Sprache kann man ewig diskutieren, ohne zu einem Ergebnis zu kommen.

- **firewall**: Bei Übersetzungen von Microsoft: "Der Firewall" (vermutlich in Anlehnung an "Der Feuer-Wall". Überall sonst: "Die Firewall" (die Feuer-Mauer)
- **e-mail** In Deutschland: "die E-Mail". In Österreich: "das E-Mail" oder auch "die E-Mail"
- **cola, fanta, …** In Deutschland: "Die Cola, die Fanta". In Österreich: "Das Cola, das Fanta". Die weibliche Form wird in Österreich nur von deutschen Touristen verwendet und von deutschen Immigranten, welche häufig in der Gastronomie arbeiten und von Touristen für Österreicher gehalten werden.

---

Das Folgende betrifft nicht mehr Anglizismen, wohl aber den Gebrauch von Artikeln in Deutschland und Österreich:

- Deutschland (D): "Ich habe eine Eins auf die Schularbeit bekommen." (weiblich)
- Österreich (Ö): "Ich habe einen Einser auf die Schularbeit bekommen." (männlich, mit -er am Ende)
- D: "Die Cola schmeckt aber gut." (weiblich)
- Ö: "Das Cola schmeckt aber gut." (sächlich) (vergleiche auch: "*Das* neue Cola von Red Bull", denn Red Bull ist ein österreichisches Unternehmen)
- D: "Der neue Sakko von Otto gefällt mir." (männlich)
- Ö: "Das neue Sakko von Otto gefällt mir." (sächlich)
- D: "Ilse isst einen Joghurt." (männlich)
- Ö: "Ilse isst ein Joghurt." (sächlich)
- D: "Dr. Müller hat eine interessante Offerte gemacht." (weibl. mit -e am Ende)
- Ö: "Dr. Müller hat ein interessantes Offert gemacht." (sächl. ohne -e am Ende)

In Österreich werden mehr deutsche als österreichische Zeitschriften angeboten und daher auch gekauft und gelesen; Kinofilme werden immer in deutschem Deutsch synchronisiert, nur in Ausnahmefällen wird zusätzlich auch eine Fassung in österreichischem Deutsch angeboten; im Kabelfernsehen und per Satellit kann man rund 50 deutsche Kanäle aber nur 4 oder 5 österreichische empfangen. Durch diese Übermacht deutscher Medien in Österreich wird auch das österreichische Deutsch (das ja den Status einer eigenständigen Sprache hat) vom deutschen Deutsch immer mehr verdrängt, und vor allem Jugendliche und junge Erwachsene in den größeren Städten Österreichs sprechen miteinander nicht mehr österreichisches Deutsch, sondern deutsches Deutsch. Das Wort "Buben" wird so gut wie gar nicht mehr verwendet, man spricht nur noch von "Jungen" oder "Jungs". "Erdäpfel" und "Paradeiser" findet man kaum noch im Supermarkt oder auf der Speisekarte, stattdessen stehen da seit ca 15 bis 20 Jahren "Kartoffeln" und "Tomaten". Dafür hält sich aber die "Marille" sehr standhaft, vermutlich weil viele Österreicher (noch) gar nicht wissen, dass man im Ausland "Aprikose" dazu sagt.

Weiter deutsch-österreichische Unterschiede (nur eine kleine Auswahl):

**anziehen**

In Deutschland kann man alles, was man am Körper trägt, anziehen: Ich ziehe einen Hut an, ich ziehe die Brille an und ich ziehe die Krawatte an. In Österreich kann man nur solche Kleidungsstücke anziehen, in die man hineinschlüpft: Ich ziehe die Hose an, ich ziehe die Jacke an. Aber Hut, Brille und Krawatte kann man in Österreich nicht anziehen: Ich setze den Hut auf, ich setze die Brille auf, ich binde mir die Krawatte um.

**Uhrzeit**

- Die Uhr zeigt 9:15 Uhr. In Deutschland: "Viertel nach neun". In Österreich: "viertel zehn". In manchen Regionen auch, vor allem, aber nicht nur, wenn Dialekt gesprochen wird: "Viertel über neun".
- Die Uhr zeigt 9:45 Uhr. In Deutschland "Viertel vor zehn". In Österreich: "dreiviertel zehn".

**Aussprache von Markennamen**

- colgate: Wird in Deutschland wie ein deutsches Wort ausgesprochen ("kolgate"). In Österreich wird es englisch ausgesprochen (koulgeit).
- Michelin:Wird in Deutschland wie ein deutsches Wort ausgesprochen ("michelin"). In Österreich wird es französisch ausgesprochen (mischlö).

**Bedeutung von Wörtern**

- "Abgehen". Deutschland: "Mir geht einer ab" heißt: "Ich ejakuliere." In Österreich heißt derselbe Satz: "Mir fehlt jemand" (Der Lehrer zählt nach der Busfahrt die Schüler durch, es ist einer zu wenig. Er ruft laut zu seinem Kollegen: "Mit geht einer ab!")
- "Sessel, Stuhl". Ein Stuhl ist in Deutschland ein ungepolstertes Sitzmöbel. Ein Sessel ist weich und gepolstert. In Österreich ist jedes Möbelstück, das zum Sitzen bestimmt ist, ein Sessel. Zu harten ungepolsterten Sesseln kann man auch "Stuhl" sagen, "Sessel" ist auch dafür gebräuchlicher. Ein weiches, gepolstertes Sitzmöbel ist in Österreich ein "Fauteuil" (französisches Fremdwort).

Comment: Sehr schön, und mir weitgehend geläufig, aber zum Großteil offtopic, weil es von den Unterschieden A/D bei Artikeln zu anderen Unterschieden wechselt. Konzentriere Dich bitte auf die Frage.

Comment: "Ich habe einen Einser auf die Schularbeit bekommen."  "Ilse isst ein Joghurt." 
 
 
Als Nicht-Muttersprachler verstehe ich plötzlich, warum ein paar (deutsche) Kumpels manchmal so komisch klingen !

Comment: Deutschland ist ein sehr viel heterogenerer Sprachraum, als es dieser Beitrag darstellt. Sowohl "viertel zehn" als auch "dreiviertel zehn" werden in vielen Gegenden verstanden oder sogar vorrangig gebraucht (z.B. da wo ich aufgewachsen bin - in Sachsen). _Der_ Sakko habe ich noch nie gehört, "Einser", "Zweier" usw. hingegen schon so oft, daß ich es für normalen (west?-)deutschen Sprachgebrauch halte. "Etwas geht mir ab" für "etwas fehlt mir" (z.B. ein aus Zeitgründen jetzt nicht mehr ausübbares Hobby) wird auch in Bayern (Süddeutschland?) gebraucht.

Comment: @Matthias absolut. Ich lebe nun schon seit über zwei Jahren glücklichst in Österreich und habe festgestellt, daß die Österreicher das deutsche Deutsch kaum besser kennen als wir das österreichische (ich hatte aufgrund der Fernsehsender anderes erwartet). So hatten wir an der Uni Wien eine lange Diskussion, die davon ausging, in Deutschland verstehe niemand die Formulierung „Das geht sich nicht aus“. Ich habe nur Deutsche getroffen, die diese Formulierung kennen. Trotzdem ist die Antwort interessant.

Comment: Ich sagte schon vor meiner Ankunft in Österreich: „das Sakko“, „etwas geht mir ab“, „die Brille/ den Hut aufsetzen“. xDie Brille anziehenx empfinde ich als himmelschreiend falsch. Übrigens schreibt unsere  österreichische Professorin in allen Fällen „die Brillen“. Ist das so üblich? Das ist mir in Deutschland noch nie aufgefallen.

Comment: Die Hosen und die Brillen werden von vielen Menschen prinzipiell im Plural verwendet, weil sie aus zwei gleichen Teilen (2 Hosenbeine, 2 Gläser) bestehen. Aus demselben Grund gibt es auch im Englischen die *trousers*, *pants* und *glasses* gar nicht in der Einzahl, sondern nur im Plural. Das Deutsche ist da freizügiger und lässt auch die Einzahl zu. Ob, und wie sehr, die Verwendung regionale Schwankungen aufweist, weiß ich nicht.

Comment: Zu *»die Österreicher kennen das deutsche Deutsch kaum besser als die Deutschen das ö. Deutsch«*: Das bezweifle ich sehr stark. Ich glaube, du meinst aber ohnehin etwas anders. Ich glaube du meinst: *»Die Österreicher wissen nicht, wie gut Deutsche das österreichische Deutsch verstehen.«* Ich habe vor allem in den letzten Jahren gelernt, dass wir das tatsächlich oft falsch einschätzen, weil wir eben keine Deutschen sind, und in diesem Punkt in Wahrheit raten müssen. ...

Comment: ... Ich glaube aber dennoch, dass ein durchschnittlicher Österreicher, der allein durch die deutschen Lande zieht, die ortsansässige Bevölkerung besser versteht als ein Deutscher, der in Wien schon mal an der Kaffeekarte verzweifelt (Was ist ein *Einspänner*? Und was macht ein *Kapuziner* auf der Kaffeekarte?)

Answer (score 4):

Siehe hier:

> So ist es heute noch im Deutschen: Entlehnen wir ein Wort aus dem Englischen, erhält es das Standardgenus: der Code, der Gig, der Thread, der Hoax und viele, viele mehr.
>
> Nur Wörter, die eine Hand­lung bezeichnen oder beinhalten, werden Neutra: das Tuning, das Must-have. Der Smoking sieht zwar aus wie ein Gerund auf ·ing, be­zeich­net aber keine Hand­lung und hat daher Stan­dard­genus.

Quelle: http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php

Answer (score 3):

### 0. Keine Hunderprozentigen Gesetze

Fremdworte, die aus dem Englischen ins Deutsche übernommen werden, erhalten ihr Geschlecht per Konvention. Man kann in diesem Prozess der Konventionsfindung ein paar Regularitäten beobachten, aber daraus lassen sich deskriptiv keine hunderprozentig belastbaren Gesetze ableiten.

Es lässt sich etwa beobachten, dass Fremdworte eine Zeitlang konkurrierende Genera haben. Ein Beispiel dafür ist das Wort *Firewall*, das sowohl mit femininem und maskulinem Geschlecht existiert.

Für alle einfacheren Regeln lassen sich Ausnahmen finden. In der Literatur sind verschiedene Faktoren identifiziert worden, die die Genusfindung beeinflussen. Bisher ist keine Regel ausfindig gemacht worden, welche die Genusfindung ohne Ausnahmen erklären kann: Diese Faktoren sind einerseits nicht abschließend – sie können nicht alle Fälle erklären. Andereseits sind sie auch zu grob – mitunter stehen sie in Konkurrenz zueinander, und in Fällen der Konkurrenz fehlt es an Kriterien, um zu beschreiben, welcher Faktor den Ausschlag gibt. Hierfür ist *Firewall* ein Beispiel: hier scheinen mehrere semantische Analogien (zu *die Mauer* und *der Wall*) möglich, die in Konkurrenz zueinander stehen.

Ich referiere im Folgenden aus [Agnieszka Nyenhuis, Karin Pittner: *Faktoren der Genuszuweisung – ein Vergleich anhand von Anglizismen und Polonismen.*, in: Germanica Wratislaviensia Bd. 136 (2012), S. 123-147.](http://staff.germanistik.rub.de/karin-pittner/wp-content/uploads/sites/22/2020/10/2012_GenusAnglizismenPolonismen.pdf). Diese Arbeit listet die die wichtigsten Prinzipien auf, welche die Findung des Genus im Deutschen mitbedingen. Alle direkten Zitate und die meisten Beispiele sind aus dieser Arbeit. Die Arbeit ihrerseits stützt sich in Betracht auf die hier diskutierte Frage stark auf Alexander Onysko: *Anglicisms in German. Borrowing, Lexical Productivity, and Written Codeswitching.*, de Gruyter, Berlin/New York 2007.

### 1. Morphologische Faktoren

Morphologische Faktoren sind Faktoren, die der *Form* des Worts entspringen. Wenn erkennbar ist wie die Form sich zusammensetzt, kann eine Analogie zu im Deutschen vorhandenen Konstruktionen entstehen:

> In einer durchsichtigen Morphemkonstruktion erhält die Entlehnung
> das Genus, das im Deutschen durch das dem Fremdaffixen entsprechende heimische Affix bedingt ist.

#### 1.1 Suffixe und Pseudosuffixe:

Bestimmte Endungen des Englischen werden als Suffixe erkannt. Man spricht von "Suffix-Analogie". Unter Anderem sind das Endungen, die aus dem Lateinischen stammen und analog in romanischen Sprachen und auch im Deutschen existieren. Beispiele für Suffix-Analogie sind:

- *-er* – *der Trainer*, *der Stalker*, *der Hacker*, *der Fidget Spinner*
- *-ty* / *-ity*, analog zu Lateinisch *-tas* / *-itas*, deutsch *-ität* – *die Publicity*, *die Society*
- *-ion* / *-tion*, analog zu Lateinisch *-ion* / *-tion*,  – *die Action*, *die Connection*, *die Session*
- *-ness*, funktional analog zu deutsch *-heit* / *-keit* – *die Fitness*, *die Fairness*, *die Cleverness*
- *-ing*, funktional analog zur Verbsubstantivierung – *das Training*, *das Briefing*

Hier ist nicht die phonetische Struktur (der Klang) ausschlaggebend für die Genuszuweiseung, sondern die funktionalen Eigenschaften des Suffix.

### 2. Semantische Faktoren

Semantische Faktoren sind solche, die in der Bedeutung des Wortes liegen.

#### 2.1. Semantische Entsprechung

Anglizismen können ihr Genus aus einer semantischen Entsprechung zu einem existierenden deutschen Wort erhalten:

Beispiele:

- *der Shop* – *der Laden*
- *das Girl* – *das Mädchen*
- *die Band* – *die Kappelle*, *die Gruppe*
- *die Story* – *die Geschichte*
- *der Beat* – *der Schlag*, *der Puls*
- *der Laptop* – *der Computer*, *der Rechner*

Die Worte *das Business*, und *das Poster* sind Beispiele dafür, wie semantische und morphologische Faktoren miteinander konkurrieren können.

#### 2.2. Natürliches Geschlecht

> Personenbezeichnungen richten sich in ihrem Genus nach dem Sexus des Referenten [...]

Beispiele:

- *die Queen*
- *die Lady*
- *die Nanny*
- *der Cowboy*
- *der Callboy*
- *der Sunnyboy*

Hier ist *das Girl* ein Beispiel für eine Konkurrenz mit dem Faktor der semantischen Entsprechung.

#### 2.3. Bedeutungsprinzip

> Wörtern aus einer Reihe von semantischen Feldern weisen häufig jeweils das gleiche Genus auf [...] So sind z.B. generische Personenbezeichnungen ohne Bezug auf das natürliche Geschlecht, Jahreszeiten, Monate, Tage; Himmelsrichtungen und alkoholische Getränke maskulin, Bezeichnungen für Blumen feminin, chemische Elemente und Metalle neutral.

> Andere semantische Regeln sind, dass Musikstile (*Blues*, *Hiphop*, *Jazz*.
> *Pop* etc.) maskulin sind, sowie Autotypen (*Jeep*, *Minivan*, *Rolls*, *Truck*) und alkoholische Getränke (*Cocktail*, *Drink*, *Whisky*).

> [...] generische Personenbezeichnungen werden [...] zu Maskulin.

Beispiele:

- *der Bodyguard*
- *der Comedian*
- *der Darling*
- *der Tennis-Crack*
- *der DJ*

#### 2.4. Leitwortprinzip

> [...] ein entlehnter Artbegriff erhält das Genus des deutschen Gattungsbegriffs.

Beispiele:

- *der Charleston*, *der Disco-Fox*, zu der Tanz
- *das Boxcalf*, zu das Leder

### 3. Default-Geschlecht

Die meisten Anglizismen, die unter keine der anderen Kriterien fallen, erhalten männliches Geschlecht.

> Darunter sind eine Reihe von Nomina, die durch Konversion aus Verben entstanden sind. Hierzu bemerkt Onysko: „they have lost the verbal processual meaning and denote bounded events or states”. Damit drücken sie individuative, konkrete Konzepte aus und fallen daher in die Klasse der maskulinen Nomina.

Es liegt in der Natur der Definition dieses Kriteriums, dass man nie ganz sicher sein kann, ob nicht ein anderer, verdeckter und bisher unerkannter Faktor ausschlaggebend ist. Beispiele für Default-Maskulinum könnten sein:

- *der Download*
- *der Song*

Answer (score 2):

Eine sehr interessante Frage. :)

Ich neige ebenfalls dazu @splattne zuzustimmen. In der einschlägigen Literatur wird darauf verwiesen, die entsprechenden Nomen zugleich mit ihren Artikeln zu erlernen.

In Zweifelsfällen scheint es eine gute Praxis, ein Nomen mit unbekanntem Artikel um ein Nomen mit bekanntem Artikel zu erweitern. So kann beispielsweise aus dem/der umstrittenen Nutella das unumstrittene Nutellaglas werden.

Nichtsdestotrotz gibt es gewisse Tendenzen, wie [Artikel im deutschen Sprachgebrauch](http://www.duden.de/sprachratgeber/die-verteilung-der-artikel-genusangabe-im-rechtschreibduden) verteilt sind. Einzelne [Internetseiten](http://deutsch.lingo4u.de/grammatik/nomen/genus) scheinen sogar Zusammenhänge zwischen Wortendungen und Genus erkannt zu haben. Eine generelle Regel gibt es jedoch nicht, im Zweifelsfall hilft also nur die Konsultation eines Wörterbuchs. Leider.

Comment: Unbekannt ist eigentlich jeder Artikel einer Fremdsprache. Das englische hat ja nun keine Geschlechter, aber das Französische, welches ja 2 hat, weicht auch oft vom deutschen ab. (der Schuh, die Socke/la chaussure, la chausette). Wenn es keine allgemeingültige Regel gibt, dann fällt man immer auf die Empirie zurück, und mit ausreichend Sturheit wird man nie schauen, was die anderen machen, sondern selbst versuchen, stilbildend zu wirken.

Comment: Zum Trick der Artikelergänzung: Viele Freunde der Anglizismen behaupten, diese würden benutzt, weil sie oft kürzer sind. Wenn ich allenthalben ein ~ding anhänge, um 'das' davorzusetzen, wird damit die Begründung für den Anglizismus überhaupt hinfällig. Auch mag es bei Produkten noch angehen, ein Wort anzuhängen, aber bei Anglizismen wirken solche Chimären sicher oft ebenso befremdlich wie ein unvermuteter Artikel.

Answer (score 2):

Ergänzung: In den Fällen, in denen die Assoziation zu einem deutschen Äquivalent offensichtlich oder naheliegend ist, wird in der Regel das Geschlecht des Äquivalentes verwendet. Ausnahmen entstehen gerne, wenn unterschiedliche Äquivalente herangezogen werden, aber das ist auch bereits bei regionalen Unterschieden im Deutschen der Fall:

Beispiel:

- Das Radio (-gerät) im norddeutschen Raum,
- Der Radio (-apparat) im süddeutschen Raum.

Bei Komposita reicht es dabei aus, wenn das letzte (geschlechtsbestimmende) Substantiv der Zusammensetzung derart zugeordnet werden kann.

Eine Rolle spielt auch die tatsächliche oder vermutete etymologische Herkunft, wenn ein englisches Wort erkennbar aus dem Lateinischen stammt, wird es im deutschen in der Regel analog behandelt und erhält sein lateinisches Geschlecht zurück.

Comment: Wie bereits in anderen Kommentaren: nicht überzeugend. Gerät ist im süddeutschen auch sächlich - wieso greift man im Süden zum Apparat, und im Norden zum Gerät? Wieso heißt es dann nicht das Fernseher/der Fernseher (Fernsehergerät/Fernsehapparat)? 2. Frage: Gibt es Beispiele für solche Anglizismen mit lateinischen (und, ich vermute, griechischen)? Wieviele Leute haben die aber parat, um sie populär zu machen?

Comment: der Radiogerät wird nie Müde, der Radiogerät schläft nie ein, der Radiogerät ist immer vor dem Chef im Einstaz....

Comment: Der Fernseher kommt vom Seher und nicht vom Fernsehgerät, würde mein Bauchgefühl sagen ;)

Comment: @Jan Ich gehe stark davon aus, daß „Fernsehapparat“ vor allem wegen des damaligen Stellenwertes als Statussymbol gewählt wurde. Daraus ergab sich dann „der Fernseher“.

Answer (score 1):

Mir ist auch keine allgemeingültige Regel bekannt. Im Gegenteil, selbst bei einem Wort muss es nicht zwangsläufig auch ein klares Geschlecht geben.

Für mich (und eigentlich die meisten Leute, die ich kenne) heißt es zum Beispiel **der Laptop** und **die E-Mail**, aber es gibt auch Ausreißer, für die es **das Laptop** und (noch seltsamer) **das E-Mail** heißt.

Ich denke das sind einfach Dinge, die man lernen (und akzeptieren?) muss.

Comment: Das E-Mail vielleicht von 'das Emaille'? :) Der E-Mail ist mir schon begegnet (Hast Du den E-Mail bekommen?), aber das?

Comment: Mir ist mal angetragen worden, dass für "importierte" Fremdwörter das Neutrum immer der richtige Artikel wäre, außer das Fremdwort hat sich bereits voll in die Sprache integriert. Aber ich finde auch, dass es an einigen Stellen seltsam klingt (wobei das Laptop noch wirklich gut kling, m.E.)

Comment: @userunknown: Emaille war bei mir bisher immer "die". http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&search=Emaille