# Der, die oder das E-Mail?

Tags: gender, anglicism

Is there an official rule on whether it’s *die E-Mail* or *das E-Mail?* I’ve heard people use both, although more commonly the female form.

Comment: Shouldn't it be called by its full name? I.e. "Die E-Mail-Nachricht"?

Comment: What is "das Email"? Das Emaille kenne ich.

Comment: @user: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Email

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/928/266

Answer (score 37, accepted):

According to the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/E_Mail), both feminine and neuter genders are possible. My personal experience is that indeed most people use *die E-Mail* in Germany; according to the comments, people tend to say *das E-Mail* in Austria and Switzerland. Note that the Duden lists the word as *E-Mail*, not *Email* (the latter being also a German word for *enamel*).

Comment: Yes, in fact I have not heard anyone actually using "das E-Mail". Might have to do with the fact that "Post" is female as well, which "E-Mail" translates into, and "das Email" would be the proper enamel gender, as you pointed out.

Comment: I actually know a few people who say _das E-Mail_. (I also know someone who says _die E-Post_, which I like very much `:-)`)

Comment: @ Hendrik, thanks, good point about "E-Mail".

Comment: Personal experience: Our Austrian customers tend to say *das E-Mail*, just like *das Cola*.

Comment: Der Brief, die Post, das Schreiben. Man suche es sich aus. Siehe auch die Diskussion [Wonach richtet sich das Geschlecht eines Anglizismus?](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/928/266)

Comment: In Switzerland people tend to say "das E-Mail" instead of "die E-Mail".

Comment: Can't talk about Austria or Switzerland, but all the geek communities in Germany that I've joined or visited are using "die E-Mail" or "die Mail".

Comment: In my experience, "die E-Mail" predominates in Germany, but "das E-Mail" in Austria and Switzerland

Comment: E-Mail, die oder das Wortart: Substantiv, feminin oder Substantiv, Neutrum Synonyme zu E-Mail
(EDV) E-Brief, E-Post, elektronische Post, elektronischer Brief, Mail Dieses Wort gehört zum Wortschatz des Zertifikats Deutsch. Uwe Keim: definitely not, "Die E-Mail-Nachricht" is a redundant tautology / pleonasm.
user unknown: das Email ist das Synonym zu Emaille, nachschlagen bei Duden.
Hendrik Vogt wrong answer! http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/E_Mail (wer lesen kann ist im Vorteil ;)

Comment: @guestpost Im Deutschen mag man tatsächlich meist E-Mail sagen, wo E-Mail-Nachricht richtiger wäre, aber es ist nun einmal so, dass „Mail“ „Post“ heißt und nicht „Brief“.