# What gender does a “Virus” have?

Tags: noun, gender

In German there is some confusion on the gender of *Virus* where both masculine and neuter are used:

> Das Influenzavirus ändert jährlich seine Oberflächenstruktur.
>   Ich habe mir den Virus im Schwimmbad gefangen.
>   Der Virus wird von ihrem Computer gelöscht.

[Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Virus) does not help much here:

> *das, außerhalb der Fachsprache auch: der Virus; des Virus, Viren*

At some point back in time I learned that a virus in a medical sense always is *das Virus* whereas it is always used as *der Virus* in computing. However I couldn’t find any reference for this, and I have heard both variants in both settings.

Can both genders be used alike in modern German or is there any preference when to use one or the other?

Comment: bei Sirup und Ketchup hab ich auch schon des öfteren das/der gehört.

Comment: What is it you don't understand about the Duden entry?

Comment: @Phira: They don't define *"Fachsprache"*. Computing does have technical terminology too, we all know that ;)

Comment: There is no doubt that this refers to medical language. Also, "Fachsprache" does not mean that a doctor will always use "das".

Comment: A related Question about foreign words and gender: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus

Comment: [Das Blog ist tot, es lebe der Blog](http://www.scilogs.de/wblogs/index.php?op=ViewArticle&articleId=3034&blogId=42#comment-33077) sehr interessant Ansichten eines Sprachwiss. zu der Thematik

Comment: Ich sage immer "Der Laptop". Mein ehem. Bitbewohner in meiner WG sagte immer "Das Laptop". Ich habe "Das Laptop" immer gehasst.

Comment: Questions that can easily be answered by using a dictionary should be closed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think the Duden entry is very explanatory. Doctors and the like tend to use only *das* whereas laymen use both *der* and *das*. However I can't exactly confirm the former; I know/visit too few doctors.

Based on my experiences it looks like this:

- when the medical term is meant, people tend to use *der* or *das* interchangeably
- when the computer virus is meant, people (almost?) exclusively use *der*

Comment: Yes, Duden is correct, but from my personal experience I think that 'das Virus' is vanishing in scientific contexts as well - maybe a little slower, but steadily. I believe, we're not far from the point where saying 'das Virus' will sound a bit smart-alecky to most people even in medicine.

Answer (score 8):

You can use both, so who cares?

Ok, ok, some data:

Google results for *[der Virus](http://www.google.com/search?q=der%20Virus&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=%22der%20Virus%22&pbx=1&oq=%22der%20Virus%22&aq=f&aqi=g-v2&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=348437l350542l0l350992l2l2l0l0l0l0l163l284l0.2l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b12f5e501efbd0e5&biw=1012&bih=745)* shows 1,130,000 hits.
Google results for *[das Virus](http://www.google.com/search?q=das%20Virus&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=%22das%20Virus%22&pbx=1&oq=%22das%20Virus%22&aq=f&aqi=g-v2g-m1&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=341045l342805l0l343295l2l2l0l0l0l0l156l224l1.1l2l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b12f5e501efbd0e5&biw=1012&bih=745)* shows 1,410,000 hits.
The first results show both variants, because they ask which version is correct ;) But the "medical" gender wins by close vote (yeah, this is no election, I know, I know).

Now let us look at the special term for computer virus:
[Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computervirus) tells us, that both genders are allowed, but *der Computervirus* is only colloquial used. Looks like they orientate themselves at the Duden and the medical use.

But [Heise](http://www.heise.de/) with its popular German IT Magazine c't shows a different story:
For *[das Virus](http://www.google.com/search?q=das%20Virus%20site%3aheise.de&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=dEY&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=%22das%20Virus%22%20site%3ahttp://www.heise.de/ct/&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b12f5e501efbd0e5&biw=1012&bih=745&pf=p&pdl=3000)* we got only 6 results, for *[der Virus](http://www.google.com/search?q=der%20virus%20site%3aheise.de&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=SEY&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&source=hp&q=%22der%20virus%22%20site%3ahttp://www.heise.de/ct/&pbx=1&oq=&aq=&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b12f5e501efbd0e5&biw=1012&bih=745&pf=p&pdl=3000)* 30 (why so few? It's a paper-, not an online magazine).

So your guess seems right, masculine is preferred in computing. Nevertheless you can use both.

Answer (score 5):

[Google Ngram Viewer "der Virus, das Virus"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=der%20Virus,das%20Virus&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=8&smoothing=3)
[image]

Comment: Now _this_ is an interesting (disturbing?) graph. I'm not sure if I want to know the reason for that spike.

Answer (score 5):

Well, Germans tend to try to keep the original gender of a loan word (if known and if possible).

*Virus* is Latin (meaning *poison*), and of neutral gender!

This is why people who try to remember their (especially humanistic) education will always try to keep it as a neutral gender: *das Virus,* and this is especially true in medicine, because in this field, Latin language has still a quite strong influence.

Contrast to this, the use of this word in computer technology is rather new. My impression is (without wanting to take the time to google for statistics) that IT technology is dominated by people to have a rather low (almost non-existing) interest for classic languages.
Therefore the word *Virus* has been *re-interpreted* by people who were simply inspired by the fact that it ends with *-us.* Even in Latin, most *-us* words are masculine. (*Virus* and *domus* are the only exceptions I know.)

Due to what I said above, Germans also tend to believe that all *-us* words should be masculine.
Therefore people who do not know the real Latin gender (or do not care) tend to use it as a masculine word, and since the number of such people has been constantly increasing over the years, the use of *das Virus* is slowly decaying. Probably medicine is the main refugium for the neutral gender.

Since the Duden has always had the policy of accepting general habits, it tends to simply accept both genders.

Comment: 1) “*Virus* and *domus* are the only exceptions I know” – There are quite some of third-declension neutral Latin words ending on *-us,* e.g., *corpus, genus, opus.* Also, there is the feminine *humus.* 2) Note how *virus* is special insofar as it is the only neutral second-declension word ending on *-us.*

Comment: The statement "Germans tend to try to keep the original gender of a loan word" holds for exactly two original languages, namely Latin and Classical Greek. For loan words from other languages, such as English, French, or Italian, the original gender is rather irrelevant (e.g., *Computer* is neuter in English and masculine in German, *Garage* is masculine in French and feminine in German, and *Konto/Conto* is masculine in Italian and neuter in German).

Comment: Eine andere Ansicht ist, dass intellektuelle Deutsche dazu tendieren, alle englischen Fremdwörter, die Sachen bezeichnen, als sächlich zu betrachten (etwa das Blog), weil es im englischen dann immer "it" heißt.