# Englische Worte in deutscher Grammatik - aber wie?

Tags: grammar, english-to-german

Tagtäglich benutzt man Worte aus dem Englischen im Deutschen; gerade im IT-Umfeld, aus dem ich stamme, sind sie allgegenwärtig.

Bei Nomen ist der Begriff selbst unverändert, hier stellt sich nur die Frage nach dem richtigen Artikel. Oft ist mir dabei schon die Erklärung über den Weg gelaufen, dass der Artikel der deutschen Entsprechung genommen wird, wobei hier aber oft verschiedene Auffassungen herrschen:

> die E-Mail -> die elektronische Post
>
> das E-Mail -> ?

Bei Verben ist es schon schwieriger, hier muss das englische Wort in die deutsche Konjugation gebracht werden. Hierbei habe ich die Erklärung im Ohr, dass man vorne und hinten an den Infinitiv des englischen Verbs die deutschen Vorsilben bzw. Endungen anhängt, z. B.

> gedownloadet

Unabhängig davon nun, ob man das ganze gut oder schlecht findet – wie schreibt man es richtig? Gibt es auch dafür offizielle Regeln?

Comment: [gedownloadet oder downgeloadet?](http://notizen.joergkrusesweb.de/n-2007-4/ge-down-ge-loadet.html)

Comment: Was das Geschlecht betrifft ein Duplikat: http://german.stackexchange.com/q/928/266

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Offizielle Regeln, wie Lehnwörter zu flektieren sind, gibt es meines Wissens nicht.

Welchen ungeschriebenen Regeln die Flexion von Anglizismen folgt, hat das [Institut für Deutsche Sprache](http://ids-mannheim.de) in einem [Grammatik-in-Fragen-und-Antworten-Artikel](https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/fragen/140) untersucht.

Answer (score 6):

Substantive sind nicht unbedingt unverändert. Richtig ist übrigens "*E-Mail*" (auch um Verwechselungen mit *[Email](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Email)* auszuschliessen). **Ich denke mit der Artikelübernahme für die deutsche Entsprechung fährt man richtig (der Duden erlaubt beides für E-Mail - Wortart: Substantiv, feminin oder Substantiv, Neutrum).** Analog aber zum Beispiel "*der Thread*". Allerdings höre ich "*der Account*" weitaus öfters als "*das Account*" (Das Konto). In dem Fall hat es wohl etwas mit subjektivem Sprachgefühl zu tun, der Duden erlaubt auch hier beides.

Bei Verben gibt es jedoch keine Diskussion. Wenn man diese eindeutscht und es dann z.B. zur Partizip-Perfekt-Bildung kommt, dann müssen die deutschen Endungen benutzt werden, also "*[downgeloadet](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/downloaden)*" und niemals eine Faux-Anglais Endung a la "*downgeloaded*".

Comment: Ich bin der gleichen Meinung - nur ist eine solche Regel denn auch irgendwo festgelegt oder hat sich lediglich diese Art der Benutzung etabliert?

Comment: Die Verbregel ist einfach. Man entlehnt Woerter, aber keine grammatikalischen Regeln. Die Sache mit den Artikeln ist da schon schwieriger. Aber im Lichte der ewigen, unseeligen Nutella-Diskussion, behaupte ich einfach mal, dass es dafuer keine klare, schriftliche Regel gibt. Insofern sollte fuer offizielle Text gelten, erlaubt ist, was der Duden zulaesst.

Comment: Früher schrieb man Emaille aber auch Emaille, und nicht Email. "Der Account", weil "der Zugang".

Comment: Das hat mir jemand wegkorrigiert :) Bzgl "account" - okay, dann wird es aber falsch uebersetzt, das waere doch dann der Access.

Comment: @Jules: Ich dachte `Access` sei `Zugriff`? :) Im Ernst: Es sind oft mehrere Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten gegeben, und die haben oft nicht das gleiche Geschlecht. [siehe auch Geschlecht e. Anglizismus](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus)

Comment: I've got access to a building (Zugang) and I've got access to my account (Zugriff). I can't have an account to my building (well maybe for my building) :S Insofern ist sicher beides moeglich, aber account ist doch recht eindeutig eine Art Benutzer-Konto (zumindest im Kontext einer Internet-Seite). Die Uebersetztung "Zugang" fuer Account sehe ich nicht. Das sieht dict.leo uebrigens auch so.

Comment: Ich gebe dir aber natuerlich recht, dass das Geschlecht sich bei Uebernahme aendern kann und das auch zulaessig ist (ich wuerde nach Gefuehl auch "der Account" sagen).