# Is the plural form of "Oscar" "Oscars" or "Oscare"?

Tags: grammatical-number, loanword, declension

I was wondering how to decline an English loanword like "Oscar". I know that there are no fixed rules. Sometimes the native declination is adopted, sometimes words are declined according to corresponding German rules.

> "The Artist" hat dieses Jahr 5 Oscare gewonnen.
>   Unter den Gewinnern der Oscars war Angelina Jolie.
>   Von den Oscaren hatte Meryl Streep auch einen gewonnen.

These examples all sound odd. What would be the grammatically correct way to decline "Oscar" in German?

Comment: Ist "Oscar" ein Lehnwort? Ich denke es ist ein Eigenname.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[It is done with "s"](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Oscar).

> 11 Oscars gingen an ... (Plural)
>
> Gewinner der Oscars für beste Musik und beste Regie war ... (Genitiv)
>
> Der Film wurde mit den Oscars ... (Dativ)
>
> Ich freue mich auf die Oscars... (Akkusativ)

I do agree that your examples sound odd though. The first one would be fine with s.
The second one would be phrased as:

> Unter den Oscargewinnern...

The third one would probably be:

> Meryl Streep gewann einen der Oscars.

Technically *von den Oscars* would be correct too, but it doesn't sound good.

Answer (score 3):

This question is related to [the one about English words in German Grammar](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3858/englische-worte-in-deutscher-grammatik-aber-wie).

"Oscars" is much more common than "Oscare", as a Google search for the terms

- ["oscars gewonnen"](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22oscars%20gewonnen%22)  and
- ["oscare gewonnen"](http://www.google.de/search?q=%22oscare%20gewonnen%22)

shows.

I don't think there's an alternative to these two. You should be fine with "Oscars".

Comment: I'd say _much more common_ is quite an understatement. If you look closer at the search results, then all the (presently 9) results for "oscare gewonnen" that are actually in German are from `www.schuleundkultur.ch`. And those 3 results in German actually contain the same text. (Soon there'll be some more results from german.se ...)

Comment: You're right of course. I didn't look closely enough at the results themselves. I just checked how many there were.