# Why is it "der Bikini"? Shouldn't the noun be feminine?

Tags: noun, gender, loanword

I can understand that some German nouns (e.g. Mädchen) might just always have been whatever gender the noun is, and the explaintion is lost to the mists of time. But Bikinis were invented in the 1940s. So why is it "der Bikini"? Why is bikini a male noun in German? Surely "die Bikini" makes much more sense!

Was there some meeting where they added Bikini to the German language/dictionary, and they decided it would be a masculine noun?

Comment: Maybe, because it is a kind of Badeanzug (= der Badeanzug).

Comment: Another idea: In French it is 'le bikini' (also male). Maybe it is taken from there and the question is: Why is bikini male in French?

Comment: No. They made it male because "die Badehose" for men was female already. Two females are one too many. Seriously, like most of the time the answer here is "it is what it is" - in many cases it does not make sense to ponder about the gender of nouns in the German language. Learn them along with the meaning and you're fine.

Comment: I know often it just *is*, and we cannot know. But Bikini, being a recent invention, I thought there'd be more details available.

Comment: Zum Beispiel "Mädchen": In Verniedlichungsform sind alle Nomen neutral. Die Maid, das Mädchen; der Hase, das Häschen; der Tisch, das Tischchen.

Comment: If it was female, then "Das ist mein(e) itsie-bitsie teenie-weenie Strandbikini" wouldn't have the correct meter any more. But seriously, _maillot de bain_ (as well as _Badeanzug_) is male, so it makes sense. But whatever the reason, Louis Réard called it **le** bikini.

Comment: Es gibt keine Regel wonach Dinge in die weibliche Sphäre gehören weiblich sind oder Dinge die zu Männern gehören männlich. Die Frage basiert also schon auf einer Fantasieregel. Es gibt also keine Ausnahme die legitimiert werden müsste.

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Just because a central premise of the question (garments for females should be grammatically female) turned out to be debatable does not mean that it was not a justified assumption.

Comment: also see this related Q & A: http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/5545/for-new-words-which-are-often-nouns-who-sets-the-gender

Answer (score 18):

First of all, there is no clear scheme after which the genders of loanwords are determined (see also [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus)). Even with words that are in the process of being loaned right now, native speakers find it hard to agree on the gender (e.g., I have seen any gender for *Blog)* and even if they do, it’s hard to pinpoint the reason.

But let’s have a look at *Bikini:*

- When *Bikini* was loaned, the closest existing word was *der Badeanzug.* Therefore it is likely that its gender was either directly adopted or is a remnant of the composite *Bikini-Badeanzug,* which might have been used when the word was new and not well-known.
- You claim that *die Bikini* would make more sense. But there is no reason why something that is predominantly worn by women should be of female grammitical gender (consider also, e.g., *der Rock, das Kleid, die Krawatte).* Given, it is associated **with** women for this reason, but it is not associated **as** a women.

  As a contrasting example: My intuition often disagrees with some old household devices (whose name did not come with a clear preference for grammatical gender) being regarded as grammatically female (e.g., *die Moulinex).* I would hypothesise that this is because they performed what was considered women’s work at the time of their invention and therefore were associated **as** women.
- Finally speaking of what makes sense, giving a garment for women a grammatical gender other than female actually has one advantage: One of the advantages of grammatical gender is that it may clarify to which word a pronoun relates, e.g.:

  > Meine Schwester trug einen blauen Bikini. Er sah grauenvoll aus.
  >   Meine Schwester trug einen blauen Bikini. Sie sah grauenvoll aus.

  These sentences are only disambiguous, because the grammatical gender of Bikini is not female. Since female is almost certainly the predominant grammatical gender among words appearing together with garments for women, making giving garments for women grammatically female is most prone to cause ambiguities.

  However, I am rather sure that such thoughts never influenced the choice of grammatical genders.

Comment: Wie bestimmt man denn den nächstliegenden existierenden Ausdruck? Wieso nicht der BH, der Schlüpfer, die Unterhose, die Unterwäsche, die Bademode, die Badehose usw.? Wo gibt es denn die Regel, dass existierende Begriffe die der Sache nahekommen ihr Geschlecht verleihen? Gibt es dafür erwiesene Beispiele? 2.: Was ist denn die Moulinex? Ich habe eine Braun (Küchenmaschine) und einen Braun (Elektrorasierer). 3.: Schönes Beispiel, aber wie Du selbst schreibst kaum vorstellbar, dass dies die Sprecher beeinflusst hat. "Der Mann schenkte ihr einen Bikini. Er sah grauenvoll aus." :) Richtig ist 2a).

Comment: @userunknown: Es gibt keine feste Regel, dass naheliegende Dinge das Geschlecht einem Fremdwort das Geschlecht verleihen und ebensowenig eine eindeutige Methode das nächstliegende Ding zu bestimmen. Es gibt aber eine Tendenz, das Geschlecht danach auszuwählen, wenn es keine anderen Kriterien (Wortendung, usw.) gibt – und mehr habe ich auch nicht behauptet. 2. Ein Mixer (oder etwas Ähnliches) der Firma Moulinex – und bevor sich jemand beschwert: Es ist nicht meine Idee, die Dinger mit dem Firmennamen zu bezeichnen.

Comment: Den nächst liegenden existierenden Ausdruck bestimmt man nach der Art des Gegenstandes. Die Moulinex ist eine (Die Maschine) Der Braun ist ein (Der Rasier) Aber warum es der Rasierer heist? Wahrscheinlich weil früher Männer andere Männer rasiert haben. Der Friseur, die Frisöse.

Comment: @DisplayName: *Der Rasierer* ist wie alle derartigen Tätigkeitsbezeichnungen *(Maurer, Verkäufer, Henker, …)* grammatikalisch männlich. Da braucht es keine gegenstandsspezifische Historie.

Comment: Der Rasierer ist vor allem wahrscheinlich ein Rasierapparat und daher männlich...

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Jetzt sagst Du es gäbe eine Tendenz. Wie kommst Du darauf? Hast Du Dir das eben ausgedacht, oder gibt es dafür Belege? Du scheinst zu glauben, dass man, wenn man es nicht weiß, einfach die nächstbeste Vermutung als Tatsache verkaufen darf.

Comment: @DisplayName: Die Antwort "nach Art des Gegenstandes" hilft nicht weiter, weil viele Gegenstände vielgestaltig sind. Walnuss kann als Frucht und als Holz aufgefasst werden, als Farbe, als Baum, usw. Mit unterschiedlichen Bezeichnungen kommen aber unterschiedliche Geschlechter, selbst für sehr ähnliche Dinge, etwa die Bank aber das Kreditinstitut, oder der Laden, das Kaufhaus, Die Moulinexmaschine ist übrigens mit großer Sicherheit auch ein Apparat, alias Gerät. Du musst nicht nur versuchen Deine Ideen zu belegen, sondern vor allem zu widerlegen.

Comment: @userunknown: Siehe diverse Antworten zu [dieser Frage](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus), aber auch [hier](http://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/institut/professuren/korpuslinguistik/lehre/alte_jahrgaenge/ws-2003/hs-phaenomene-deutsch/pdf/phaeno-kp-Anglizismen.pdf/view) oder [hier](http://www.canoo.net/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Nomen/Genus/Fremdwort.html). Außerdem: Das diese Kriterien einem helfen, das Geschlecht irgendeines Fremdwortes (geschwege denn aller) zu bestimmen hat ja auch niemand behauptet.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Was soll ich da denn sehen? Kannst Du ein einziges Wort nennen, bei dem man das Geschlecht auf die strittige Weise bestimmt hat oder kannst Du das nicht? Gesucht ist nicht ein Wort bei dem es zufällig passen würde, auch wenn die Bestimmung des Geschlechts nicht so passiert ist. Wenn man nicht vorher weiß, ob das Verfahren funktioniert, ist es schlicht wertlos.

Comment: @userunknown: Wo habe ich etwas behauptet, woraus folgen würde, dass man bei irgendeinem bestimmten Wort das Geschlecht auf eine bestimmte Weise fest bestimmt?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Du hast geschrieben: "When Bikini was loaned, the closest existing word was der Badeanzug." Kann natürlich sein, dass das eine völlig irrelevante Bemerkung ist, und Du auch hättest schreiben können, dass damals 28°C im Schatten herrschten oder hellblau die Farbe der Saison war.

Comment: @userunknown: Und es geht weiter mit »Therefore it is **likely** …«

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: Und Du meinst eine Sache sei bereits dann wahrscheinlich, wenn man es behauptet, oder wie soll ich die Antwort verstehen? Wieso sollte es deswegen wahrscheinlich sein? Weil in 3 von 5 Fällen, wenn ... dann ...? Es ist aber bisher kein einziger Fall dokumentiert, in dem das Geschlecht von einem naheliegenden anderen Begriff abgeleitet worden wäre.

Comment: @userunknown: Da es sich hierbei um eine probabilistische Aussage handelt, kann es auch keine entsprechenden Beispiele geben. Genausogut könnte man abstreiten, dass Rauchen oder hohe Strahlungsdosen krebserregend sind, weil es keinen einzigen dokumentierten Einzelfall gibt, in dem sie nachweislich den Krebs ausgelöst haben.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: So? Woher weiß man denn dass Strahlungsdosen Krebs auslösen? Vielleicht aus Tierversuchen, bei denen man die Zahl der Krebsfälle ohne und mit Strahlung gezählt hat? Und wo ist der entsprechende Versuch für diese Frage zur Sprache? Außerdem ist die Aussage falsch. Für tausende Aussagen zur Wahrscheinlichkeit kann man sehr wohl einzelne Beispiele aufzeigen. In über 50% der Bundesligaspiele sind 2 oder mehr Tore gefallen - soll ich ein Beispiel nennen?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried thinking about "Die Bikini" and it just hurts.
Same if you think about "der Kappe".

But we have "Die Hose" und "Der Hut."

Wir haben Anzug, Badeanzug und Badehose. Die Hose = Die Badehose
Der Anzug, Der Badeanzug, Bikini, der Badeanzug mit weniger Stoff für Frauen.

Aber die Bikinihose das Bikinihöschen und das Bikini - Oberteil. Aber "Der BH".

Das Teil -> Das Oberteil
Die Hose -> Die Bikinihose

So I'd say it inherited the gender from the closest existing thing which is "Der Badeanzug" Which again is a compound word with "Der Zug."