# Welches Genus bekommen Fremdwörter?

Tags: gender, loanword

Als Jugendlicher im Ausland wurde es mir eingetrichtert, im Deutschen würden Fremdwörter stets das sächliche Genus bekommen.

Inzwischen scheint es mir so, als hätte man diese Faustregel komplett über Bord geworfen, und meine Frau sagt auch, es würde sich kein Mensch mehr an diese Regel halten (auch wenn sie ihr auch bekannt ist). Ich arbeite im Ingenieurwesen und habe ständig mit z.T. sehr neuen Fachbegriffen zu tun, die aus dem Englischen übernommen worden sind. Eine konsistente Verdeutschung ist nicht zu erkennen (auch wenn ich eine Neigung zum Maskulinum empfinde!). Trotzdem sind die Menschen oft irritiert, wenn in einem Gespräch ein Begriff das "falsche" Genus (was auch immer das "richtige" sein soll) bekommt. Nachschlagen kann man diese Begriffe jedoch nicht. Das ist ziemlich ärgerlich :)

Meine Frau sagt, sie orientiere sich inzwischen nach dem Genus des entsprechenden deutschen Wortstamms, sofern einer erkennbar ist.

Hier ein Beispiel aus der Informatik: definierte Variablen in einem Computerprogramm landen in einem Abschnitt des Arbeitsspeichers, der im Englischen häufig "workspace" genannt wird, also einem "Arbeitsraum". Der Wortstamm ist "Raum", der im Deutschen maskulin ist, also heißt es "der Workspace".

Ist es tatsächlich so? Gibt es inzwischen eine "neue Faustregel", die breite Akzeptanz gefunden hat? Wenn ja, ist diese irgendwo belegt?

Comment: Können wir diese Frage bitte auch an diese https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus verlinken? Die Frage und Antworten sind dort um ein vielfaches ausführlicher.

Comment: Übrigens ist keins der Duplikate in der Duplikat-Liste beim Schreiben meiner Frage aufgetaucht, auch in meinen Suchergebnissen nicht, sonst hätte ich sie nicht gestellt :)