# Geschlecht von "Socket"?

Tags: gender, technical-terminology

Welches Geschlecht hat "Socket" im Sinne von [Kommunikationsverbindungen zwischen Systemprozessen](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_local_inter-process_communication_socket)? Im [allgemeinen Wikipedia-Artikel über Sockets](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_(Software)) wird das Wort sowohl sächlich als auch männlich verwendet.

Comment: Männlich natürlich. Mit welchem sächlichen deutschen Wort sollte es denn korrespondieren? Mit dem männlichen "der Sockel" passt es jedenfalls. Man könnte es allenfalls "die Socket" nennen, analog zu "die Buchse".

Comment: @Janka, wann hört der Irrglaube auf, das Geschlecht richte sich nach einem korrespondierenden deutschen Wort?

Comment: @CarstenS Sobald du uns das Gegenteil beweist?

Comment: Das ist lustig: Wiktionary kennt das Wort »Socket« nicht, und gibt stattdessen Auskunft über das kleingeschriebene Wort »socket«: »2. Person Plural Konjunktiv Präsens Aktiv des Verbs *socken*«. Ich kannte dieses Verb bisher nicht, habe nun aber gelernt, dass es ein scherzhaftes Synonym für *gehen* und auch ein saloppes Synonym für *laufen, rennen* ist. Wieder was gelernt.

Comment: *Der Socket* ist auch wirklich nur ein computertechnischer Fachbegriff. Sag "der Socket ist soundso" und jeder Programmierer (der sein Geld wert ist) weiß, was gemeint ist.

Comment: @tofro Ich wüßte nicht, mit welchem korrespondierenden Wort
man *"das Racket"* (= *"der Tennisschläger"*) oder *"die Courage"*
(= *"der Mut"*) erklären könnte.

Comment: @Uwe - ***le** courage* gefällt mir gut, hier hat es nicht mal das originale Genus geschafft, ins Deutsche übernommen zu werden. Aber wie wäre es mit der wörtlicheren Übersetzung "die Beherztheit"? Oder der Lautähnlichkeit zu "die Rage"? Es gibt viele Möglichkeiten, wo das Genus eines Lehnwortes herkommen kann. Die Übernahme von einem bedeutungsgleichen deutschen Wort ist eine davon. Nicht die einzige, zugegebenermaßen. Aber auch keine, die man rundweg ausschließen kann.

Comment: Die Besonderheit ist hier gerade, daß im Französischen Wörter mit der Endung "-age" immer Maskulina
sind (bei "la plage" gehört "age" zum Stamm).
Bei der Übernahme ins Deutsche werden sie aber konsequent zu
Feminina.

Comment: @tofro Das ist ja gerade Carstens Punkt: Das Genus eines Fremdwortes richtet sich *nicht immer* nach einem korrespondierenden deutschen Wort.

Comment: @uwe ...und das hat keiner behauptet. Und ich lese Carstens Kommentar als "...richtet sich *nie* danach".

Comment: @tofro Also ich lese Jankas ersten Kommentar als "es richtet sich immer nach
einem korrespondierenden deutschen Wort" und Carstens Antwort
als Widerspruch dazu, d.h., "es richtet sich *nicht* immer nach
einem korrespondierenden deutschen Wort".

Comment: Dann liest du falsch. Die Frage ist mit welchem sächlichen deutschen Wort "socket" denn korrespondieren sollte. Und da ist keins. Damit hat dieser Weg schonmal ein Minus. Für maskulin und feminin gäbe es hingegen Kandidaten.

Comment: @Janka _Song_ korrespondiert recht eindeutig mit _Lied_, trotzdem hat sich dort das Maskulinum gegen das Neutrum durchgesetzt. Zumindest die Behauptung, es wäre allein aufgrund der Korrespondenz mit Sockel (was für die IT-Bedeutung des Begriffs nicht mal eine passende Übersetzung wäre) **"natürlich"**, _Socket_ als maskulin anzunehmen, scheint mir da doch etwas gewagt.

Comment: Code von Leuten, die "das Socket" sagen, wird von mir besonders gründlich auf sonstige Absonderlichkeiten untersucht.

Comment: Wenn das Geschlecht mal übereinstimmt, mal nicht, dann ist die Frage zu stellen nach welchen Regeln es mal übernommen wird und mal nicht. Ansonsten ist es reine Koinzidenz und hilft nicht bei der Bestimmung des Geschlechts, kann also keine Regel sein. Der Irrglaube von der Übernahme  aus der Herkunftssprache führt immer wieder dazu, dass für Dinge aus dem englischen it=>es angenommen wird. Bis auf (nicht wenige) Ausnahmen ist aber das Maskulinum generisch, also "der Socket".

Comment: Der Sockel -> Der Socket, Die Halterung -> Die Socket, Das Empfangsstück --> Das Socket. Ich stimme für der Sockel.

Answer (score 4):

Fremdwörter aus modernen Sprachen bekommen im Deutschen üblicherweise

1. entweder das Genus eines bedeutungsgleichen oder -ähnlichen Wortes,
2. oder das Genus anderer ähnlich klingender Wörter.

Typische Beispiele für Fall 2 sind die Endungen
*-tion* oder *-age*: Fremdwörter mit diesen Endungen sind
im Deutschen immer Feminina, ganz unabhängig von ihrer Bedeutung.

Bei "Socket" stehen diese beiden Regeln im Widerspruch:
Die infragekommenden Übersetzungen für "Socket" sind Maskulina
(Anschluß, Sockel) oder Feminina (Steckdose, Muffe).
Andererseits sind andere Fremdwörter, die auf *"-et"* oder *"-ett"*
enden, üblicherweise Neutra (unabhängig davon, ob bei *"-et"* das
*"t"* stumm ist oder nicht), beispielsweise
*"Ticket", "Racket", "Plazet", "Filet", "Toupet", "Bidet", "Couplet", "Quartett", "Falsett",
"Menuett", "Barett", "Stilett", "Jackett"*.
Beides zusammengenommen führt dazu, daß sich Muttersprachler
in ihrem Sprachgefühl nicht einig sind und mal das Maskulinum,
mal das Neutrum bevorzugen.

Comment: Wenn schon, dann willst du noch (3): Das Genus, das sie in der Originalsprache haben - ergänzen. Bei Anglizismen zugegebenermassen eher selten, bei z.B. aus dem Spanischen übernommenen Worten aber ziemlich häufig.

Comment: @tofro Deswegen hatte ich "moderne Sprachen" geschrieben.
Bei Übernahmen aus dem Lateinischen und Altgriechischen
wird fast immer das Genus übernommen.
Bei den modernen Sprachen taugt das Genus in der Originalsprache
aber selten als Erklärung.
Sicher gibt es Wörter, die in der Originalsprache und
im Deutschen zufälligerweise
das gleiche Genus haben, aber ich kenne kaum ein
Fremdwort aus einer modernen Sprache, das das Genus der
Originalsprache beibehalten hat, obwohl Bedeutung und Klang
etwas anderes nahelegen würden. ...

Comment: @tofro
... (Dagegen findet man leicht Wörter, deren Genus sich nach der
Bedeutung richtet, obwohl Genus in der Originalsprache und
Klang etwas anderes nahelegen, z.B.
"der Feta" (= "η φέτα" (f) = "der Schafskäse"),
und auch Wörter, deren Genus sich nach dem Klang richtet,
obwohl Genus in der Originalsprache und Bedeutung
etwas anderes nahelegen, z.B.
"die Visage" (= "das Gesicht" = "le visage" (m)).)

Comment: Natürlich gibt es zum Beispiel den Fall, dass jemand bewusst das Genus aus dem Französischen übernimmt (wobei dabei natürlich das arme Neutrum zu kurz kommt), dann kann man gerade wieder beim Front National beobachten.

Comment: Ist Spanisch keine moderne Sprache?

Comment: @tofro
Schon, aber die gute Korrelation zwischen spanischem und deutschem
Genus läßt sich halt auch problemlos durch die Wortgestalt erklären. ...

Comment: ... Wir wissen, daß das Genus in der Originalsprache
bei Fremdwörtern aus dem Englischen und Französischen
so gut wie keinen Einfluß auf das deutsche Genus hat.
Bei italienischen Fremdwörten ist die Korrelation etwas besser,
bei spanischen noch besser (wenn auch längst nicht perfekt, z.B.
"das Embargo", "das Chili con Carne",  "die Jalapeño",  "der Espuma",
"das Alpaka", "das Eldorado", "das Lasso", "die Chorizo").
Dafür könnte es zwei Erklärungen geben: ...

Comment: ... Möglichkeit 1: Anders als
bei englischen und französischen Fremdwörtern folgt der deutsche
Muttersprachler bei spanischen der Tradition frühneuzeitlicher Gelehrter,
schlägt das korrekte spanische Genus nach, und übernimmt es ins Deutsche.
Möglichkeit 2: Der deutsche Muttersprachler tut das, was er sonst auch
tut, und orientiert sich an der Wortgestalt. Er macht also Wörter auf "-a"
zu Feminina und Wörter auf "-o" wahlweise zu Maskulina oder Neutra;
damit trifft er in geschätzten 70% aller Fälle zufällig das spanische Genus.
Welche Erklärung klingt plausibler?

Comment: @CarstenS Ja, diese merkwürdige Angewohnheit mancher Journalisten.
Ich ordne das unter "bildungsbürgerliche Besserwisserei" ein.
Oder auch unter "falsch".

Comment: @Uwe Ich würde sagen, beides. Kategorisch eins davon auszuschließen, läge mir, vor allem, wenn es sich um Sprache dreht, vollkommen fern.

Comment: @Uwe "Das Alpaka" ist ein schlechtes Beispiel. Das Wort stammt nicht aus dem Spanischen, sondern aus dem Quechua, wo es ähnlich dem Englischen keine "direkten" Genera gibt. Lediglich für ein paar wenige Adjektive (z.B. "alt") gibt es wie beim Wort "Schwester" bzw. "Bruder" im Deutschen eine männliche und eine weibliche Übersetzung.

Comment: Wörter bekommen im Deutschen, wenn nichts dagegen spricht, das generische Maskulinum. Fälle und Erklärung, die dagegensprechen, sind bei Belleslettres http://www.belleslettres.eu/content/deklination/genus.php zu erfahren, eine schriftl. Zusammenfassung würde Stunden kosten. Ausnahmen wie "Der Zölibat" kommen im Fachjargon vor und sind nicht falsch, aber die Muttersprachler, die Unikat, Triumphirat, Prädikat kennen, handeln auch nicht falsch und setzen sich langfristig meist durch (der Laptop).

Comment: @userunknown Die Beispiele "Embargo", "Chili", "Jalapeño", "Eldorado", "Lasso" und "Chorizo" aus dem Spanischen sind wohl die besten Beispiele dafür, dass diese Regel nicht stimmen kann.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Inwiefern? Es kann doch sein, dass der Genuszuordnung im Deutschen wie im Spanischen oft die gleiche, inhaltliche Regel zu Grunde liegt, und damit keine der Sprachen etwas aus der anderen übernimmt. Bei Eldorado dachte ich übrigens erst "der Eldorado", weil ich an den Fluss dachte - das Eldorado im Sinne von das Paradies hattest Du wohl vor Augen. Jedenfalls dementiert der Eldorado schon mal die Klanghypothese. Bei Wörtern auf "~tion" handelt es sich auch meist um Abstrakta und Abstrakta sind im Indogermanischen feminin. Daher belegt auch eine Klangkoinzidenz ...

Comment: ... die man ins Felde führt, wenn sie passt, und nicht ins Feld führt, wenn sie nicht passt, rein gar nichts. Ebenso ist ja oft unklar, ob ein Wort jetzt aus dem Lateinischen oder Französischen oder Englischen ins Deutsche kam - zumindest für Laien - selten nachvollziehbar. Wegen "das Gulasch" und "der Gulasch" würde ich auch zu "das Chili" und "der Chili" neigen (für das Gericht, die Pflanze oder Frucht wiederum "die Chili").

Comment: @userunknown Deine Hypothese war, dass Fremdwörter im Deutschen in der Regel maskulin sind. Die von mir aufgeführten Beispiele sind Beispiele für Wörter, die im Deutschen weiblich oder Neutrum sind, obwohl sie in der Originalsprache männlich sind. Bei "die Jalapeño" sprechen wirklich ausnahmslos alle Regeln, die ich jemals gelesen habe, dagegen, dass es sich im Deutschen um ein weibliches Wort handelt. Ein Beispiel also dafür, dass es entweder keine allgemeingültige Regel gibt, oder dass für diese Regel viele Ausnahmen gelten müssen....

Comment: @userunknown ... Und woher will man wissen, ob ein ganz bestimmtes Wort - z.B. "Socket" - eine Ausnahme darstellt oder nicht?

Comment: Was sind das für Regeln, die im dt. dagegen sprechen, dass es Jalapeno weiblich ist? Die Bohne, die Schote, die Frucht, die Melone, ... - es gibt massig weibliches Gemüse. Ich hätte auch zu "die Jalapeno" tendiert, fand im Duden aber überraschend "der Jalapeno". Die Sprache ist ja v.a. etwas empirisches: Wenn die Verwender eines Wortes alle (oder die meisten) aus den falschen Gründen einen bestimmten Artikel verwenden, dann bürgert er sich ein und wird zum richtigen Artikel. Nur kann er im Laufe der Geschichte, wenn er in neue Milieus vordringt, das Geschlecht wieder wechseln, wie der Blog.

Comment: Ausführlich, aber ohne simple Antwort, Scholten: [der oder das Gulasch?](https://www.belleslettres.eu/content/deklination/genus-essen.php) (belleslettres)

Answer (score -1):

In the cited Wikipedia article, I can only find *one* neuter use of *socket* and all others in masculine gender. At least in one single article consistent usage of gender for one single term should be aimed for, so I would consider that simply an error. In case it is not an error, the frequency should also give a strong hint on what is more common usage.

It is (somewhat) common practice for germanized words from other language to assume the gender of the closest literal translation, here "Sockel", which is masculine (Various other mechanisms exist as well: See [here](https://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/de/institut/professuren/korpuslinguistik/lehre/alte_jahrgaenge/ws-2003/hs-phaenomene-deutsch/pdf/phaeno-kp-Anglizismen.pdf) for a nice elaborate presentation on the topic and [here](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus) on an internal discussion). "Closest", however, is often a matter of taste (one example being "e-Mail", which could receive gender from "elektronische Post", "elektronische Nachricht", "elektronischer Brief",....) Thus, loanwords commonly exist in several genders for quite some time until the community of users of the language decide on the most common or useful practice. A nice example is "Dschungel" that used to take all three possible genders through maybe 150 years until it finally settled in masculine). In the "e-Mail"-Example, this process apparently has not finally settled, this word is commonly used in both masculine and feminine forms - Although in my experience, the feminine form "die e-Mail" prevails (This fact is even reflected by [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/E_Mail)).

For *socket* there is actually no obvious reason to use neuter - Other than that this term *somewhat* correlates to *das Interface* (which is an English loanword as well and apparently received its gender from "das Zwischenstück"), I cannot see the slightest reason to use neuter. In my personal practice, I have *never* heard someone use "Socket" in neuter.

Comment: Gibt es einen bestimmten Grund, warum du auf eine Frage, die auf Deutsch gestellt wurde, in einer Fremdsprache antwortest?

Comment: Nö. Ich merk' das nicht einmal...

Comment: Eine Google-Suche nach "der Socket ist" bzw. "das Socket ist" liefert ein Verhältnis von 1500 (m) zu 755 (n). Das Neutrum kommt also auf immerhin ein Drittel aller Fälle.
Mit "ich kenne das nicht, also ist es falsch" lehnst Du Dich weit
aus dem Fenster.

Comment: @Uwe Die Schlußfolgerung "kenne ich nicht, also falsch" steht nirgendwo in meiner Antwort. Die hast du wohl selbst hineininterpretiert. Im Gegenteil - Ich habe versucht, an Beispielen klarzustellen, dass durchaus mehrere Versionen parallel existieren und richtig sein können. Darüberhinaus halte ich es durchaus für legitim, meine eigene Erfahrung zu äußern. Und 2:1 ist i.Ü. durchaus eine Hausnummer.

Comment: Zum Vergleich: "die Mail ist"/"das Mail ist" liefert ein Verhältnis von 47200 (f) zu 7020 (n), also beinahe 7:1.

Comment: Gegen die Annahme sprechen Experimente, die zeigen, dass willkürlich erstellte Wörter, die es gar nicht gibt, im Deutschen von unterschiedlichen Sprechern meist das gleiche Geschlecht zugewiesen bekommen, dass es also eine grundlegende Regel geben muss, die Muttersprachler kennen, ohne sie verbalisieren zu können, ohne sich der Regeln bewusst zu sein.

Comment: @userunknown Hmm. Das ist nicht meine Annahme, sondern die von Sprachwissenschaftlern. Siehe Link in meiner Antwort.

Comment: @tofro: Da steht nichts zur Frage, ob das Geschlecht des bestpassendsten dt. Wortes übernommen wird. Dass mehrere, konkurrierende sprachliche Geschlechtsformen von unterschiedlichen Übersetzungsmöglichkeiten herrühren steht da ebenfalls nicht. "Das E-Mail" kann ebenfalls daher kommen, dass im Engl. alle Objekte sächlich sind, und die ersten Verwender daher von "it" fälschlich auf "sächlich" geschlossen haben.

Comment: @userunknown dann hast du nicht richtig gelesen-da steht unter "Lexikalischer Ähnlichkeit " *das Lehnwort nimmt das Geschlecht seiner deutschen Übersetzung an*

Comment: Wie man "Der Song" sieht ist das schlicht falsch, Duden hin oder her.

Answer (score -1):

Ich habe den folgenden Text zum Thema "Genera bei Fremdwörtern" gefunden: [Link](https://blog.canoonet.eu/2007/09/24/geschlecht-von-fremdwortern/)

Zwei Zitate daraus:

> - Vielfach gibt es dabei ... regionale Varianten wie zum Beispiel bei E-Mail: Neben **die E-Mail** gibt es ... auch **das E-Mail** ...
> - **Ob** eine der Tendenzen letzlich "gewinnt" ..., bestimmt der Sprachgebrauch.

Dies würde bedeuten, dass sowohl "**die** E-Mail" als auch "**das** E-Mail" "richtig" sind, so lange beide Varianten in Gebrauch sind und die Bundesländer keine Regelung erlassen haben.

Dasselbe gilt natürlich auch für Fachbegriffe wie "Socket", sofern beide Varianten in Gebrauch sind.

Eine Bitte:

Ich habe meine Antwort jetzt komplett überarbeitet. Bei einem "Downvote" hätte ich gerne einen Kommentar, was an der Antwort nicht gut ist.