# Release: Das, Der und Die

Tags: spelling, article

Der Duden behauptet, dass das Wort [Release](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Release_Version_Software) mit **jedem** Geschlechtswort benutzt werden kann.

Wow! Wie kann das sein? Warum ist es so?

Heißt das eigentlich, dass ich das Wort wie ich will sagen kann? z.B.

> *Das Release des Albums* | *Ich habe ihm einen Release dieser Software besorgt*

oder im Genitiv:

> *Eine Version der Release* | *Der Produzent des Releases*

Ich habe gedacht, dass das Wort weiblich ist, da 90% der Wörter mit "e" am Ende weiblich sind. Aber im Deutschen muss man immer aufpassen und die Hypothesen vielmal überprüfen. :)

Comment: Als Österreicher würde ich klar _das_ bevorzugen, aber _der_ Release klingt zumindest akzeptabel. Das weibliche Geschlecht ist für mich die schlechteste Alternative.

Comment: Siehe auch [https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus)

Comment: Die Hypothese mit dem "e" ist bei Lehnwörtern so glaube ich nicht haltbar - vor allem da das "e" in *Release* auch im Deutschen stumm ist ;).

Comment: Ich bin da ganz und gar mit dem Duden einig - Mein Sprachgefühl kann je nach Kontext mit allen drei Genus leben. Für ein *Software-Release* würde ich allerdings vorzugsweise Neutrum annehmen, weil ich das so gewohnt bin, für eine Schallplatte aus irgendeinem Grund Femininum, und für eine Veranstaltung, die im Rahmen einer Veröffentlichung statfindet und *Release* heißt, aus irgendeinem anderen für mich im Moment nicht greifbaren Grund Maskulinum.

Comment: @tofro, wow! Danke. Das ist sehr hilfreiche Erklärung.

Comment: Nein, leider ist das überhaupt keine Erklärung - Ich würde nämlich selbst gerne verstehen, *warum* mir mein Gefühl diese Einordnung nahelegt.

Comment: Das wird wohl die Gewohnheit sein.

Comment: Anderes Wort volatilen Artikelgeschlechts: der/die/das Butter. - Klar, im Standarddeutschen ist es "die", aber gerade bei der Butter pflegen einige Dialekte eine Transgenderkultur. (Ist ja schon oft diskutiert worden hier.)

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Na, das ist schon was anderes, abgesehen davon, dass ich "das Butter" noch nie gehört habe, ist es was besonderes, dass der Duden alle 3 Genus als **in der Hochsprache** akzeptiert sieht. Ich glaube nicht, dass es viele solcher Beispiele gibt, mir fällt auch grade kein einziges anderes ain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ich plädiere für "der Release".

Das Maskulinum ist das "Standardgenus", das neue Fremdwörter außer unter bestimmten Umständen erhalten. Man werfe einen Blick auf diese Zusammenstellung von teils neuen, teils älteren Anglizismen, die das nahelegen:

[image]

Ausnahmen sind z. B. Wörter, die mit einer konkreten Handlung verknüpft werden ("ing-Wörter") oder wenn man aus vermeintlicher Weltgewandtheit meint, das Genus (oder im Englischen nicht-Genus) aus der Quellsprache übernehmen zu müssen. Weiblich sind die Wörter vorallem dann, wenn es eine Abstraktion einer Handlung ist: die Tour ("das Fahren als Gesamtes"), die Connection ("das, was beim Verbindung herauskommt").

Das Foto stammt aus "Denksport Deutsch" von Daniel Scholten, in dem das Thema der Genusbildung im deutschen in tiefgründiger und erfrischend einleuchtender Weise bis zu den urindogermanischen Ursprüngen unserer Sprache aufgerollt und behandelt wird.

Answer (score 3):

Der Duden(-Verlag) legt dies aufgrund seines Expertenstatus fest, und diesen hat er anerkanntermaßen durch Beobachtung der Praxis der deutschen Sprache. Er ist aber keine hoheitliche Sprachinstanz, und andere Beobachter haben andere Blickwinkel auf das geschriebene und gesprochene deutsche Wort.

Dies zur Frage, wie es sein kann.

Ich kenne Release nur als Neutrum und würde in Reviews andere Geschlechter hinterfragen. Tatsache ist, dass das Wort unverändert aus der englischen Sprache übernommen wurde, die keine Geschlechter kennt, so dass es also kaum mehr als ein "Gewohnheitsrecht" für das sächliche Geschlecht gibt.

Comment: a) Das englische kennt "he, she, it". b) Das "it" entspricht aber nicht dem sächlichen Geschlecht im Deutschen. c) Es gibt keine Regel, aus der Ursprungssprache das Geschlecht eines Wortes dieser Sprache zu übernehmen (Le Tour de France/Die Tour de France). d) Was bedeutet "Gewohnheitsrecht" - in Anführungsstrichen und überhaupt für das Geschlecht eines Wortes. Die Gewohnheit muss doch auch erst begründet werden.

Comment: Dem ersten Absatz stimme ich zu, dem letzen mitnichten. Wie @userunknown bereits ausgeführt hat, kennt das Englische sehr wohl grammatische Geschlechter. Dessen ungeachtet gibt es keine Regel, wonach das grammatische Geschlecht eines Wortes aus einer Sprache ins Deutsche übertragen würde. Also selbst wenn _release_ im Englischen weiblich wäre, müsste es im Deutschen noch lange nicht _die Release_ heißen.

Comment: Die letztlich autoritative Instanz zu allen Fragen bzgl. einer Sprache ist der Sprachgebrauch. Wenn die Sprecher einer Sprache die Sprache in einer bestimmten Weise verwenden, dann ist das einfach so. Dann hat es auch keinen großen Sinn, nach dem Warum zu fragen.

Comment: @user unknown: he, she, it referenzieren Geschlechter von Lebewesen, jedoch wäre es mir neu, dass Dinge im Englischen ein Geschlecht aufweisen.

Comment: Mag sein, dass irgendwo "tief drinnen" die englischen Wörter noch Hinweise auf ein grammatisches Geschlecht liefern. Praktisch gesehen haben sie aber einfach *kein* Geschlecht. Also weder maskulin, noch feminin noch neutral. "Frische" Fremdwörter werden im Deutschen, sofern bestimmte Bedingungen nicht erfüllt sind (und das sind sie meistens nicht), zunächst immer dem männl. gramm. Geschlecht zugeordnet. Der Grund dafür liegt weit in der Vergangenheit und hat mit der Entstehung des Genus in unseren Sprachen zu tun (das im übrigen so gut wie nichts mit dem biologischen Geschlecht zu tun hat)

Answer (score 1):

> Wie kann das sein? Warum ist es so?

Diese Frage ist eng mit der Frage verwandt, wie Fremdwörter zu ihrem Genus kommen.

Mehrere Seiten im Internet besagen, dass die Sprecher zunächst dasjenige Genus verwenden, das sie für richtig halten.

Erst mit der Zeit bildet sich dann ein "richtiges" heraus, indem immer mehr Sprecher zu einem der drei Genera tendieren und immer weniger zu den beiden anderen.

Offensichtlich ist das Wort "Release" noch nicht lange genug im Deutschen vorhanden, so dass dieser Vorgang noch nicht "abgeschlossen" ist.