# Geschlecht von Kicker (Rampe / Schanze)

Tags: gender, anglicism

Im Internet bin ich auf eine [Präsentation](https://www.linguistik.hu-berlin.de/de/institut/professuren/korpuslinguistik/lehre/alte_jahrgaenge/ws-2003/hs-phaenomene-deutsch/pdf/phaeno-kp-Anglizismen.pdf) gestossen, welche 7 Regeln zur Bestimmung des Genus eines Anglizismus definiert.

1. Lexikalische Ähnlichkeit
2. Gruppenanalogien
3. Natürliches Geschlecht
4. Anzahl der Silben
5. Morphologische Analogie
6. Anglizismen aus Verb und Partikel
7. Latente oder verborgene Analogien

Nun möchte ich in einem Text das Wort Kicker (deutsch: Rampe / Schanze) verwenden und es ist mir nicht klar, ob ich jetzt "DER" oder "DIE" nehmen soll.
Die Meisten der Leute, die ich dazu befragt haben, meinen "Der Kicker" sei richtig, aber laut der ersten der 7 Regeln (Lexikalische Ähnlichkeit) würde der Genus der deutschen Übersetzung, also von Schanze oder Rampe, welche beide weiblich sind, genommen.

Was ist in diesem Fall richtig, oder kann man sogar beides verwenden?
Gibt es auch noch andere allgemeine Regeln zur Bestimmung des Geschlechts?

Comment: Warum der Downvote? Ich finde die Frage gut gestellt und komplett „On Topic“, und ausreichend Recherche wurde auch betrieben...

Comment: Siehe auch hier: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/928/wonach-richtet-sich-das-geschlecht-eines-anglizismus?rq=1

Comment: Der Haken an deiner Idee ist, dass Schanze und Rampe völlig ungebräuchlich sind (ich kannte die nicht mal) und deshalb die lex. Ähnlichkeit hier nicht greift. Ich denke, für alle Analogien und Ähnlichkeiten muss ausreichend Relevanz dieser Wörter gegeben sein. Die 7 Regeln sind also nicht ganz zu Ende gedacht. Ansonsten denke ich auch wie Torsten Link, dass einfach das Geschlecht von "Fußballer" genommen wurde, was die Leute zu 95% zu Spielern dieser Sportart sagen als deutsches Wort.

Comment: Nicht ganz außer acht gelassen werden sollte m.E., dass Substantive, die auf -er enden, fast immer männlich sind. Das Genus von "Schanze" oder "Rampe" zu übernehmen, käme mir gar nicht in den Sinn.

Comment: Worum geht es denn hier? Skateboarding?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Die von Dir verlinkte Präsentation ist -mMn- etwas unglücklich aufgebaut: Ich würde die 7 Punkte nicht gewichten, sondern als gleichwertige Kriterien nebeneinander stellen. Es wird Dann bei der Entscheidung über den Artikel diejenige Regel verwendet, die sich am „natürlichsten“ anfühlt.

In dem von Dir genannten Beispiel passt die Regel 5 „ Morphologische Analogie“ am besten:

> Durch Suffixe kann die Genuszuordnung erfolgen
>   ...
>   genus: Maskulin, Suffix: -er

Dazu kommt, dass es bereits ein bekanntes Wort „Kicker“ (umgangssprachlich Fussballer oder Tischfussball) gibt, das ebenfalls maskulin ist, und es klänge seltsam, wenn man die neue Bedeutung mit einem anderen Genus versehen würde

Comment: Wobei das Phänomen von gleichlautenden Substantiven mit unterschiedlichen Artikeln, also unterschiedlichem Genus, durchaus nicht zu vernachlässigen ist - gerade auch weil der Bedeutungsunterschied durch den Artikel gekennzeichnet wird, ohne die Notwendigkeit, aus dem Kontext zu schließen, was gemeint ist.

Comment: Das ist korrekt, nur dass hier nicht wirklich ein Bedeutungsunterschied vorliegt... der „Kicker“ (Fussballer) gibt dem Ball mit einem Kick eine neue Richtung, der „Kicker“ (Rampe) demjenigen, der drüberfährt...

Answer (score 1):

Die Vokabel tritt mit dieser Bedeutung extrem selten in freier Wildbahn auf, viele dürften sie nicht kennen.

Das Suffix legt *maskulin* nahe, was auch auf die anderen Bedeutungen zutrifft. Für die hier vorliegende Bedeutung wird es durch einen [Wikipedia-Artikel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kicker_(Sprungschanze)) gestützt.

Da sehe ich nicht viel Spielraum, wenn man Ärger mit Grammatik-Prüfprogrammen vermeiden will.