# Warum ist "Tsunami" männlich?

Tags: gender, loanword

Deutsch ist meine Muttersprache. Der Begriff "Tsunami" wurde, glaube ich, allseits bekannt durch die massiven Erdbeben im Indischen Ozean 2004 und Nordost-Japan 2011. Die japanische Sprache kennt kein grammatisches Geschlecht, aber weil es sich bei einem Tsunami um eine Art Welle handelt, habe ich früher automatisch immer "die Tsunami" gesagt.

Weil ich seit Jahren nicht in Deutschland lebe, ist mir erst durch Presseberichte aufgefallen, dass anscheinend "der Tsunami" die Norm ist ([Der Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tsunami) allerdings erlaubt beides).

Hat jemand erforscht, welche Kräfte am Werk sind, wenn Wörter aus Sprachen ohne grammatischem Geschlecht ins Deutsche (oder andere gendernde Sprachen) übernommen werden? Und wie genau ist das bei dem oder der Tsunami geschehen?

Comment: Ähnliche [Frage](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/928/1696) für Anglizismen.

Comment: Auch ganz interessant: Wie haben andere Sprachen das gelöst? Laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsunami) haben sich Polnisch und Rumänisch für Neutrum entschieden,  Tschechisch für Femininum und Französisch, Italienisch, Katalanisch, Portugiesisch und Spanisch für Maskulinum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explizit erforscht habe ich das nicht, aber es gilt hier dasselbe Prinzip, das immer erklärt, warum in einer lebenden Sprache alle Leute etwas genau so machen wie es machen und nicht anders: Das machen sie nämlich so, weil es alle anderen auch so machen.

Wenn ein neues Substantiv im deutschen Wortschatz auftaucht, muss es zwangsweise ein grammatisches Geschlecht bekommen. Die, die es als erste verwenden, vergeben intuitiv eines der drei Geschlechter, wobei sich diese Intuition häufig an Analogien orientiert, die für ähnliche Wörter gelten. Wenn es keine offensichtlichen Analogien gibt, wählt man halt irgend ein Geschlecht. Und man ist sich gleichzeitig unsicher, ob die Wahl richtig ist. Irgendwann liest oder hört man dann dieses Wort. Wenn das Geschlecht in dieser fremden Quelle mit dem selbst vergebenen Geschlecht übereinstimmt, fühlt man sich bestätigt und verwendet dieses Geschlecht weiterhin.

Wenn es nicht übereinstimmt, weiß man vorerst mal nicht, ob man selbst recht hat, oder die fremde Quelle. Dann achtet man umso mehr darauf, wie es in einer zweiten und dritten Quelle verwendet wird. Und dann richtet man sich nach der Mehrheit. Aber auch alle anderen richten sich nach der Mehrheit.

Am Ende läuft es eben darauf hinaus, dass sich jeder nach allen anderen richtet. Daher machen alle das, was alle anderen machen. So funktioniert jede lebende Sprache. Richtig ist immer, was die Mehrheit macht.

Manchmal führt dieser Prozess aber auch dazu, dass gleiche Wörter in unterschiedlichen Regionen unterschiedliche Artikel bekommen, so dass dann das Geschlecht vom geographischen Ort abhängt. Beispiel: Das Joghurt ist in Österreich sächlich, während der Joghurt in Deutschland männlich ist.

Es kommt aber auch vor, dass einzelne Wörter überregional in zwei, selten sogar in allen drei Geschlechtern verwendet werden. Hier auf German.Stackexchange wird an einer Liste mit solchen Wörtern gearbeitet: [Liste deutscher Substantive mit mehreren Genera](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/49433/1487). Das Wort »Tsunami« steht noch nicht auf dieser Liste, du kannst es gerne dazuschreiben.

Comment: Ich finde, dein zweiter Absatz lässt ein bißchen zu viel Zufall zu. Ganz so ist es in Wirklichkeit meiner Meinung nach nicht. Z.B. ist es aus irgendeinem Grund im südlichen deutschen Sprachraum wesentlich wahrscheinlicher, dass ein Neologismus das Neutrum abkriegt als die beiden anderen Genera. Es scheint also regionale Bevorzugungen bestimmter Genera zu geben.

Comment: Interessanterweise sage ich als Deutscher meistens "das Joghurt". Und im Osten Österreichs ist sie anscheinend weiblich. Siehe Duden. Man lernt nie aus.

Comment: Ich finde, dass hier nur sehr wenig Antwort steht. Das skizzierte Modell beinhaltet nur die recht einfache Aussage, dass sprachlicher Wandel diskursiv verhandelt wird - legt dem dabei noch ein m.M.n. zu stark vereinfachtes (Sprachwandel richtet sich wohl kaum einfach nach der "Mehrheit" von Individualentscheidungen, sondern es gibt sicherlich einige diesen Diskurs strukturierenden Autoritäten) Self-Assembling-Modell zugrunde - und setzt an anderen Stellen "Zufall" und "Intuition" als Erklärung an. "Zufall" ist in kausalen Modellen eine Leerstelle für "unbekannte Kausalität", "Intuition" ebenso

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach - Es geht hier ja gar nicht um Sprachwandel im üblichen Sinne, sondern um eine Art Neuschöpfung bzw. gegebenenfalls um die Anwendung verborgener Regeln. Diese Regeln könnten auf Klang-Assoziationen beruhen, auf der Ähnlichkeit von Bedeutungskonzepten, auf Prägung und Nachahmungszwang oder auf anderem. Wenn ich mir die Verbreitung von verschiedenen Virusvarianten auf der Welt ansehe, denke ich, dass Etliches dafür spricht, dass jeder das (nach)tut, was ihm von seiner Umgebung angeboten wird.

Comment: @RalfJoerres Ich bestreite nicht, dass es im Großen und Ganzen stimmt, was in der Antwort steht. Ich sage nur, dass es kaum Informationsgehalt hat.

Comment: "Diskursiv verhandeln" bedeutet nach meinem Kenntnisstand Argumentation und Reflexion. Das findet aber nur vereinzelt statt. Man geht nach Gefühl und offenkundig auch gegen Halbwissen vor, sonst müsste es m.E. wg. "die (Monster-)Welle", "die (Sturm-)Flut" f. sein. Allerdings "der Hurrikan, der Tornado" als Naturkatastrophen und "das Erdbeben" als Ursache/Begleiterscheinung. Auch "die Salami" und "das Origami" liefern keine Unterstützung für das Maskulinum. Bleibt das generische Maskulinum als Rückfalloption, wenn andere Begründungen versagen.

Answer (score 9):

Es gibt [Untersuchungen](http://mediawiki.ids-mannheim.de/VarGra/index.php/Genus#Regeln_f.C3.BCr_die_Genuszuweisung_im_Deutschen), die die Vergabe der Genera von Neologismen untersucht haben.  Es gibt anscheinend sehr viele Faktoren, die dabei wirken, und eher Tendenzen als Regeln:

1. Semantische Faktoren - Das sind so einfache Regeln wie "Automarken werden meistens Maskulina" - aktuell: "der Tesla, der Polestar", Berge sind zum großen Teil auch maskulin, Flüsse scheinen vornehmlich maskulin zu sein, Wetter- und Naturphänomene wie Winde und Stürme ebenfalls.
2. Morphologische Faktoren - Im Großen und Ganzen versteckt sich dahinter eine Regel, die z.B. Wörter mit bestimmten Suffixen ein bestimmtes Genus zuordnet:
   "-eur" aus dem Französischen: maskulin, "-ett" aus dem Italienischen: Neutrum, "-i", "-ik" und "-ion" aus dem Griechischen: feminin
3. Rein lautliche Faktoren - Hier gibt es eher Tendenzen als Regeln: z.B. Substantive, die eine Konsonantenhäufung am Anfang oder Ende haben, werden mit großer Wahrscheinlichkeit maskulin, genauso wie Substantive, die auf -u oder -i enden, während Substantive auf -a eher Feminina und Substantive auf -o eher Neutren werden.

Der Tsunami scheint unter die Wetter- und Umweltphänomene zu fallen und wie "der Orkan", "der Passat", "der Tornado" und "der Monsun" deswegen maskulin geworden zu sein.

Answer (score 0):

Tatsächlich kann Tsunami sowohl männlich als auch weiblich sein ([Duden](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Tsunami), [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Tsunami)).

Deine Frage geht also von einer falschen Annahme aus.

Comment: Wieder einmal der Hinweis: Google Ngram nützt aus verschiedensten Gründen nicht als Beleg für Häufigkeiten.

Comment: Du musst dir schon auch ein paar Treffer ansehen. Die vielen 'die Tsunami'-Trefferzahlen gehen auf Bildungen wie 'die Tsunami-Opfer', 'die Tsunami-Schäden' usw. zurück. Man muss seine Werkzeuge auch richtig benutzen, Google Ngram ist nicht grundsätzlich nutzlos, sondern liefert Ergebnisse mit begrenzter Aussagekraft.

Comment: Die Frage selbst sagt schon, dass der Duden beide Geschlechter kennt.

Comment: Ich glaube, ich habe noch nie "die Tsunami" gelesen oder gehört. Außer in meinem eigenen Kopf. Mich hat der Duden-Eintrag daher schon gewundert.

Comment: @berndbausch Ich habe auch noch nie "die Joghurt" oder "der Butter" gehört, und trotzdem kommt beides vor.

Comment: Ich will damit nur ausdrücken, dass "die Tsunami" selten sein muss. "Der Butter", "der Radio" sagt man in der Pfalz.